# How to highlight an active section on the navbar using Tailwind with Nuxt.js?

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I have a one-page website with different id sections and a navbar. I would like to change the highlighted link on the navbar when the user scrolling the page across the sections. Here is what my code looks like.

```html
<!-- components/Navbar.vue -->

<template>
  <nav class="fixed w-full px-6 py-4 bg-white">
    <div class="flex items-center justify-between">

      <div>
        <img width="32px" src="@/assets/logo.svg">
      </div>

      <ul class="flex space-x-8 text-sm text-white font-sans">
        <li><a href="#home" class="active border-b-2 border-red-500 pb-1">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#faq">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>
</template>
```

```html
<!-- layouts/default.vue -->

<template>
  <div>
    <Navbar />
    <Nuxt />
  </div>
</template>
```

```html
<!-- pages/index.vue -->

<template>
  <div>
    <Home />
    <Services />
    <Features />
    <Faq />
    <Contact />
  </div>
</template>
```

```html
<!-- components/Home.vue -->

<template>
  <section id="home">
    <div class="w-full h-screen bg-cover bg-center" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533174072545">
      <div class="flex items-center justify-center h-full w-full bg-gray-900 bg-opacity-50">
        <div class="text-center">
          <h1 class="text-blue-400 text-5xl font-black">My website</h1>
          <p class="text-white font-bold">What an awesome website</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```

Each component (`Home`, `Services`, `Features`, `Faq`, and `Contact`) have a `<section>` with their id as the example above.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I would suggest using a JavaScript Library for detection scroll sections. Libraries like [Scrollama](https://github.com/russellgoldenberg/scrollama) or [GSAP's scrolltrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/) can be used to do this. In these plugins you can set a trigger element/class/attribute. When you scroll past one of these elements, you can fire an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a dependency that allows me to exactly do what I want!

The dependency is [vue2-scrollspy](https://github.com/ibufu/vue2-scrollspy). It's not officially supported by Nuxt.js but it works perfectly. Here is how to configure it:

```js
//plugins/vue2-scrollspy.js

import Vue from "vue";
import Scrollspy, { Easing } from "vue2-scrollspy";
Vue.use(Scrollspy, { easing: Easing.Cubic.InOut });
```

```js
//nuxt.config.js

export default {
  plugins: [
    { src: "~/plugins/vue2-scrollspy", ssr: false }
  ],
}
```

Enjoy!